# Run Maven with the -e switch in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

The java web application project we are working on uses Maven and Jenkins as build tool.  The Jenkins is hosted in Client environment. Could some one please tell me how can we run Jenkins with  the -e or -x switch so that we can see detailed Maven logging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can give the appropriate switches in  the `goals` option in Jenkins job configuration

Comment: Hi  coderplus, Thanks for your reply. I do not have much experience with Jenkins, is their any specific syntax to be followed while entering goals in Goals field of Jenkins's  job configuration page. Could you pleas show an example value(with switch parameter) to be entered in  the Goals field.